# File get's fetched from S3 bucket but won't download to browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am unable to download a file from my s3 bucket to the browser.

The file is being successfully fetched as when I inspect with developer tools and view **Network** I can see the image. The problem is, that it's not either being displayed in the browser or downloaded.

I am unsure whether this may be because I need some HTML to invoke the download/display of the image returned from the backend.

This is the boto3, flask, and Python code:

```
def get_client():
    return client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=keys.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=keys.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, aws_session_token=keys.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    )

@app.route('/blah', methods=['GET'])
def o():
    s3 = get_client()
    file = s3.get_object(Bucket=keys.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key='aa.png')
    return Response(
        file['Body'].read(),
        mimetype='text/plain',
        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=aa.png"}
    )
```

Thanks

Tried changing "attachment:filename=aa.png" to include a **;** instead of **:** but still not downloading.

Comment: Couple of things:
1.  You probably don't want `text/plain` if its a binary image
2.  You should consider generating a pre-signed S3 URL and then redirecting the browser so that you don't have to pass the file through your web app.